# Phaser 2: game does`t load into WebView

Tags: android, webview, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

My application works fine in a browser on a computer and a phone chrome, but it doesn’t download to the end through WebViev of another application.
I enabled debugging in this application and look at errors through the chrome console. There is none of them. If I reload the app through the chrome device remot, it works fine. However, the first launch loads only a minimal part of resources.
On the side of the server side, nginx is configured as follows:

```
location /game {
                        alias /home/...;
                         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                         }
                         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                         }
        }
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has been resolved. It turned out that WebView incorrectly passed the window.innerWidth values, because of which all the sprites were displayed too small and were not visible. It is a pity that this problem is found only in WebView.
I just put my window.innerWidth in Boot state.

Comment: Have you tryed cordova ?